# Problem inserting nested json data (some keys not present) in PostgreSQL database with python psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I´m new to programming and I chose python (3.7) as the first working language. I have been working for 5 days on code that consumes an API and returns a nested JSON. My intention is to insert this data into a table in a PostgreSQL database. I can already insert data from other data that this API provides, but this particular JSON structure is giving me problems because my code stops working when it doesn't find a certain key inside the python object (when it doesn't exist. I need it to return as a null value on a table).
I'll set you up to make it clearer. In short, and with a piece of dummy data:

```
#Note that some keys are sometimes present and sometimes not.

myapidata = [
    {
        "MaxRpm": 2300,
        "StartPosition": {
            "Longitude": -12.3456,
            "Latitude": -78.9456
        },
        "Engine": 10623,
        "Fuel": 20.133
    },
    {
        "MaxRpm": 0.0,
        "StartPosition": {
            "Longitude": -74.1258,
            "Latitude": -96.3258
        },
        "EndPosition": {
            "Longitude": -78.9456,
            "Latitude": -85.2369
        },
        "Engine": 0,
        "Fuel": 150.35
    },
    {
        "MaxRpm": 800,
        "StartPosition": {
            "Longitude": 85.4125,
            "Latitude": -45.62145
        },
        "EndPosition": {
            "Longitude": 85.2145,
            "Latitude": 74.6789
        },
        "Engine": 104,
        "Fuel": 0.021,
        "Pulse": 7
        }
    ]

#Python Code:

import json
import psycopg2

api_json_list = json.loads(myapidata.content)

#Tried to add Null to keys not present (works with non Nested JSON):
allkeys = frozenset().union(*api_json_list)
for a in api_json_list:
    for b in allkeys:
        if b not in a:
            a[b] = None

#Insert data on PostgreSQL:

conn = psycopg2.connect ("host = my_host dbname = my_db user = my_user password = my_pass")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE mytable")

data_extract = []
def get_data():
    for data in api_json_list:
        dictionary = data
        maxrpm = dictionary['MaxRpm']
        start_lng = dictionary['StartPosition']['Longitude']
        start_lat = dictionary['StartPosition']['Latitude']
        end_lng = dictionary['EndPosition']['Longitude']
        end_lat = dictionary['EndPosition']['Latitude']
        engine = dictionary['Engine']
        fuel = dictionary['Fuel']
        pulse = dictionary['Pulse']
        data_extract.append([maxrpm,start_lng,start_lat,end_lng,end_lat,engine,fuel,pulse])
get_data() #Get a TypeError

def post_gre():
    for item in data_extract:
        my_data = tuple(item)
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', my_data)
post_gre()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

The result I hope to achieve in my database is something like the table below:

[Table with null items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDJG8.png)

Thank you for any help!

## EDIT : Answer with the correct code

```
import json
import psycopg2

api_json_list = json.loads(myapidata.content)
 
#Insert data on PostgreSQL:

conn = psycopg2.connect ("host = my_host dbname = my_db user = my_user password = my_pass")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE mytable")

data_extract = []
def get_data():
for data in api_json_list:
    dictionary = data
    maxrpm = dictionary.get('MaxRpm')
    if 'StartPosition' in dictionary:
        start_lng = dictionary['StartPosition'].get('Longitude')
        start_lat = dictionary['StartPosition'].get('Latitude')
    else:
        start_lng = None
        start_lat = None
    if 'EndPosition' in dictionary:
        end_lng = dictionary['EndPosition'].get('Longitude')
        end_lat = dictionary['EndPosition'].get('Latitude')
    else:
        end_lng = None
        end_lat = None
    engine = dictionary.get('Engine')
    fuel = dictionary.get('Fuel')
    pulse = dictionary.get('Pulse')
    data_extract.append([maxrpm,start_lng,start_lat,end_lng,end_lat,engine,fuel,pulse])
get_data()

def post_gre():
    for item in data_extract:
        my_data = tuple(item)
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', my_data)
post_gre()

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than editing your question when answered, we prefer you accept an answer. There's a little check mark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
        maxrpm = dictionary.get('MaxRpm')
        if 'StartPosition' in dictionary:
            start_lng = dictionary['StartPosition'].get('Longitude')
            start_lat = dictionary['StartPosition'].get('Latitude')
        else:
            start_lng = None
            start_lat = None
        if 'EndPosition' in dictionary:
            end_lng = dictionary['EndPosition'].get('Longitude')
            end_lat = dictionary['EndPosition'].get('Latitude')
        else:
            end_lng = None
            end_lat = None
        engine = dictionary.get('Engine')
        fuel = dictionary.get('Fuel')
        pulse = dictionary.get('Pulse')
```

Using the get method on a dictionary will return the value if it exists or None if it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!
For anyone using this code template you need to remove this part of the code:
#Tried to add Null to keys not present (works with non Nested JSON):
allkeys = frozenset (). union (* api_json_list)
for a in api_json_list:
     for b in allkeys:
         if not in:
             a [b] = None